# Escaping strings in a Windows Batch For Loop

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, escaping

I'm having problems with the following code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%MYFILE_PATH%) do (
    [other stuff]
    echo %%A>> "%MYFILE_PATH%.scratch"
)
```

The file being read has XML in it and when < and > signs are read, the script throws errors.
How can I escape the contents of %%A to safely echo to the output file?
I don't want to put double quotes around it since it will then echo the quotes too.

Thanks

Comment: This code doesn't fail with `<>` characters, as `echo %%A` is safe against special characters (only the exlamation mark can cause problems). I assume your real code call functions or copy %%A into other variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%MYFILE_PATH%) do (
    [other stuff]
    (echo %%A)>>"%MYFILE_PATH%.scratch"
)
```

When appending the contents of %%A into another file, all that you are essentially doing is copying the file.

EDIT

```
 FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%MYFILE_PATH%) do (
    [other stuff]
    (echo %%A)>>"%MYFILE_PATH%.scratch"
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  With this there is no error any more.  But the whitespace in the line being copied is getting stripped.  Any way to prevent that?

Comment: It also seems to strip some other characters.  Like

Comment: It also seems to strip some other characters.  Like the line:
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.xxx.org/dtd/my-beans.dtd'> becomes  <//www.xxx.org/dtd/my-beans.dtd'>

Comment: edited my answer. The reason it was not working correctly is because in FOR /F loops, white space is the delimeter so it is automatically removed unless you specify nothing as the delims... so is a semicolon.

Comment: Never got it fully working.  Came up with a different approach to not do it within a batch file.

Comment: =( i'm sorry it didn't work out. I tested the latter part with my own XML file and it worked for me. Hope all goes well.